# Error in php code.Maybe my for loop is wrong?

Tags: php, android, mysql

ok i am not familiar with php but i have to use it for my android application to take data from mysql server.This is what i ve done so far.When i call this script from the app i want to create a new booking row and all the booked seat rows that the user selected . The above php throws an exception but i dont know where.

```
<?php
#open connection 
require("config.inc.php");
//if posted data is not empty
if (!empty($_POST)) {    


$query = "INSERT INTO booking (show_id) VALUES (:showId) ";
$query_params = array(
    ':showId' => $_POST['showId']);

$query_params1 = array(
    ':seatNo' => $_POST['seatNo']);


try {

    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
   $lastRow = $db->lastInsertId('booking');
   for($i=0; $i<$_POST['size']; $i++){
   $query1 = "INSERT INTO booked_seats (booking_id,seat) VALUES ($lastRow,:seatNo) ";
   $query_params1 = array(
    ':seatNo' => $_POST["seat{$i}"]);
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query1);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params1);
}






}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error. Please Try Again!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

$response["success"] = 1;
$response["message"] = "Reservation Completed!";
echo json_encode($response);



} 
?>
```

and this is the java code where i call the php

```
 protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String msg=null;
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> params=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("showId", showId));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("size",Integer.toString(selectedSeats.size())));
            for(int i=0; i<selectedSeats.size(); i++) {
                  params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("seat"+Integer.toString(i),Integer.to  String(selectedSeats.get(i))));  
             }  
            JSONObject jsonObject=jsonParser.makeHttpRequest( LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

            msg = jsonObject.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
        }
        catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return msg;
    }
```

I know that the tag seat* that i use may be a little bit unusual but i couldnt think anything else.
The weird think is that the above code works.It makes the changes in the database but the msg
"Reservation Completed! is never reachable because it throws an exception somewhere!

Comment: I have a register php where i use exactly the same code and this works...

Comment: What is the exception thrown?

Comment: Are you using `setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)`?

Comment: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: @Fred-ii- Look at the first example: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: yes i used setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)

Comment: @RichardBernards Sorry, I had a major "duh" moment. I honestly don't know what's up with me lately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following to echo the json:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

Also, ommit the PHP closing tag `?>`. Last but not least; make sure nothing else is being sent to output before echo-ing your JSON.

Complete answer:

```
<?php
#open connection 
require("config.inc.php");
//if posted data is not empty
if (!empty($_POST)) {    


$query = "INSERT INTO booking (show_id) VALUES (:showId) ";
$query_params = array(
    ':showId' => $_POST['showId']);

try {

    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
   $lastRow = $db->lastInsertId('booking');
   for($i=0; $i<$_POST['size']; $i++){
   $query1 = "INSERT INTO booked_seats (booking_id,seat) VALUES ($lastRow,:seatNo) ";
   $query_params1 = array(
    ':seatNo' => $_POST["seat" . $i]);
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query1);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params1);
}

}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error. Please Try Again!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

$response["success"] = 1;
$response["message"] = "Reservation Completed!";

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);

}
```

Comment: still the same problem.

Comment: @ntragas Try invoking the php-script manually from your browser and look at the json-result. I dont think it is valid JSON and without knowing what it is, it is difficult to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: looks like it is a syntax error...The changes in database are all correct...maybe i am losing something?

Comment: @ntragas What is the exact JSON generated by the PHP-code?

Comment: <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: seatNo in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\NewCashBooking1.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br />
{"success":1,"message":"Reservation Completed!"}

Comment: @ntragas OKay... just add seatNo to your params in JAVA ;)

Comment: i ve done that here  params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("seat"+Integer.toString(i),Integer.to  String(selectedSeats.get(i))));

Comment: @ntragas No, you have added params named for example `seat12`. In the PHP code you are looking for a param named `seatNo` which it cannot find... Wait one minute and I will update my answer with something that works with your code...

Comment: i thought that $_POST["seat{$i}"]); in php is the same with ("seat"+Integer.toString(i) in java

Comment: @ntragas yes it is, but you will have to remove the statement `$query_params1 = array(
    ':seatNo' => $_POST['seatNo']);` and replace it with `$query_params1 = array();` You can even completely remove the statement, since you are redeclaring it afterwards...

Comment: ouch...i checked the whole php 100 times and didnt notice this at all .Thanks a lot